# Parse.com verify email and redirect to App

Tags: ios, email, parse-platform, verification

I'm using Parse.com for my iOS App.

What I want is

1.User sign up and wait for verification email
2.User then go to email app and click on verify link
3.Redirect to App and go on

do anyone know how can I achieve this goal?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using URL schemes in iOS for more info and for tutorial goto [URL Schemes](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Assumption: email verification link generated by you (either by app side or from your server)

Answer (score 0):

You will need two things:

1. define the URL Scheme (as @raki mentioned).

   - it can be done much easier now in XCode 6, no need for the plist old editind just go to Target -> Info -> URL Types: add and write custom URL.
     (see image)
     [image: URL Scheme - XCode 6]
2. Custom the email verification email on Parse.
   Do that by going to your app dashboard -> Settings (Top bar) -> Email (Side bar):

   - make sure email verification is set to: YES.
   - go to -> Email Verification Mail Template and change template with your custom link.